# Understanding Research Paper Differences

Tags: research-process

I'm doing a high-level research which led me to the following paper - https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280389511_Quality_of_life_of_patients_with_chronic_lymphocytic_leukaemia_in_the_Netherlands_results_of_a_longitudinal_multicentre_study

As it's mentioned there are many groups of testing and comparison in the research, which are: the general population, total patient group and three groups of CLL patients.

I'm a bit confused about the definitions' differences between "the total general population" and "the total patient group".

I appreciate every advice / help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This study enrolled 144 CLL (chronic lymphocytic leukemia) patients ("total patient group"). They further grouped these patients into 3 groups according to the treatment they were receiving.

When they refer to "general population" they are referring to *norm scores*:

> For each patient, an individual norm score was
>   derived from age- and gender-matched scores of the general population on the EQ-5D [28] and EORTC QLQ-C30
>   [29]. These two studies, as reported in Refs. [28] and [29],
>   used a panel consisting of more than 2000 Dutch households, representative of the Dutch-speaking non-institutionalised population in the Netherlands.

So these scores are not part of the current study, but they are estimates from a survey of the wider population rather than patients who have CLL (you can assume they do not have CLL). "Total population" doesn't mean "all CLL", it means "all Dutch-speaking non-institutionalized people".